# How to run 2 PHP script simultaniously (non-blocking) for monitoring a popen command?

Tags: php, jquery, listener, popen, progress

**How to run 2 PHP script simultaniously (synchronous) for monitoring a popen command?**

I have a script launching a command like this:

```
7za a -t7z -mx9 backup.7z "H:\Informatique\*"
```

And I would like to display the progress of the compression on a page using jQuery and PHP.

The php script running this command look like this:

```
    if( ($fp = popen("7za a -t7z ".$GLOBALS["backup_compression"]." \"".$backuplocation.$backupname."\" \"".$pathtobackup."\"", "r")) ) {
        while( !feof($fp) ){

            $fread = fread($fp, 256);
            $line_array = preg_split('/\n/',$fread);
            $num_lines = count($line_array);
            $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['currentfile'] = $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['currentfile']+$num_lines;
            $num_lines = 0;
            flush();
        }
        pclose($fp);
    }
```

jQuery call the 7za script then jquery call the listener (*listener.php*) each 1000ms. the listener.php page contain the following code:

```
session_start();
$jobid = $_GET['jobid'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['job'][$jobid])) { $arr = array("error"=>"Job not found"); echo json_encode($arr); exit(); };
$arr = array(
    "curfile" => $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['currentfile'],
    "totalfiles" => $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['totalfiles'],
);
echo json_encode($arr);
$jobid = null;
$arr = null;
exit();
```

After the jquery call is complete (with the listener and we got a response from the server) we display the information with something normal like: `$("currentfile").text(data['curfile']);`

The problem is that the listener is in an infinite loop waiting for the first script to complete... and that's not the job of the listener... It's listening at the end of everything... when you listen, it's to know what's happening. :P

Do you have any idea what's going on and how can I fix this problem?
Or maybe you can help me with a new approch to this problem?

As always, any suggestions will be welcome.
Thank you.

**EDIT**

jQuery script:

```
function backup_launch(jobid) {
    x('jobid: '+jobid+' on state '+state);

    x('Listener launched');
    listen(jobid);

    timeout = setTimeout("listen('"+jobid+"')", 500);
    $.ajax({
        url:'backup.manager.php?json&jobid='+jobid+'&state='+state, 
        dataType:'json', 
        success:function(data)
        {
            state = 3;
        }
    });
}
function listen(jobid) {

    $.ajax({
        url:'backup.listener.php?json&jobid='+jobid, 
        dataType:'json', 
        success:function(data)
        {
            var curfile = data['curfile'];
            var totalfiles = data['totalfiles'];
            var p = curfile * 100 / totalfiles;
            x('File '+curfile+' out of '+totalfiles+' progress%: '+p);
            timeout = setTimeout("listen('"+jobid+"')", 500);

        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT 2**
I found Gearman (http://gearman.org/) but I don't know at all how to implement this and it needs to be portable/standalone... I'll try to investigate that.

**EDIT 3**

Full code for the *backup.manager.php* page. The script is sending the response right aay, but do the job in the background.

The listen.php page still wait for the command to finish before returning any results.

```
$jobid = isset($_GET['jobid']) ? $_GET['jobid'] : 0;

//Make sure jobid is specified
if($jobid == 0) { return; } 

header("Connection: close");
@ob_end_clean();
ignore_user_abort();
ob_start();

echo 'Launched in backgroud';

$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: ".$size);
ob_end_flush();
flush();




$_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['currentfile'] = 0;


// 3. When app appove backup, 
//  - Write infos to DB
//  - Zip all files into 1 backup file
$datebackup = time();
$bckpstatus = 1; //In progress

$pathtobackup = $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['path'];


/*
$query = "INSERT INTO backups (watchID, path, datebackup, checksum, sizeori, sizebackup, bckpcomplete)
        VALUES ($watchID, '{$path}', '{$datebackup}', '', '{$files_totalsize}', '', '{$bckpstatus}')"; 


$sth = $db->prepare($query);

$db->beginTransaction();
$sth->execute();
$db->commit();
$sth->closeCursor();
*/



$backupname = $jobid.".".$GLOBALS["backup_ext"];
$backuplocation = "D:\\";

if( ($fp = popen("7za a -t7z ".$GLOBALS["backup_compression"]." \"".$backuplocation.$backupname."\" \"".$pathtobackup."\"", "r")) ) {
    while( !feof($fp) ){

        $fread = fread($fp, 256);
        $line_array = preg_split('/\n/',$fread);
        $num_lines = count($line_array);
        $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['currentfile'] = $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['currentfile']+$num_lines;
        $num_lines = 0;
        sleep(1);
        flush();
    }
    pclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy,

A couple of months ago, I answered a similar question about running server-side batch jobs in a *NIX/PHP environment. If I understand correctly, your requirement is different but it's possible there might be something in the answer which will help.

[Run a batch file from my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617185/run-a-batch-file-from-my-website/13618558#13618558)

### EDIT

Here's a modified version of your client-side code. You will see that the main things I have changed are :

- to move `listen(jobid);` inside backup_launch's success handler.
- to add error handlers so you can observe errors.

Everything else is just a matter of programming style.

```
function backup_launch(jobid) {
    x(['jobid: ' + jobid, 'on state', state].join(' '));
    $.ajax({
        url: 'backup.manager.php',
        data: {
            'json': 1,
            'jobid': jobid,
            'state': state
        }
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data) {
            state = 3;
            x("Job started: " + jobid);
            listen(jobid);
            x("Listener launched: " + jobid);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            x(["backup.manager error", textStatus, errorThrown, jobid].join(": "));
        }
    });
}
function listen(jobid) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'backup.listener.php',
        data: {
            'json': 1
            'jobid': jobid
        },
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(data) {
            var curfile = data.curfile;
            var totalfiles = data.totalfiles;
            var p = curfile * 100 / totalfiles;
            x(['File', curfile, 'out of', totalfiles, 'progress%:', p].join(' '));
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                listen(jobid);
            }, 500);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            x(["Listener error", textStatus, errorThrown, jobid].join(": "));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I took a look at your answer Beetroot-Beetroot, it is similar, but my problem is more like an asynchronous request... I think it's within PHP itself, I'm trying to find a workaround.

Comment: Yes, my application was certainly different, mainly in that I needed only to kick off a server-side job and obtain feedback that it had started (or not). If I understand correctly, you want to do similar but then poll the server for progress?

Comment: Yes exaqctly, a command is running on 1 script in a while loop and increment a value stored in a session, the other script "monitor". It reads the information stored in the session. Unfortunately, the listener wait until the first script is finished before returning any results.

Comment: Sorry, I think I inverted the terms, sync/async... I need the script to be "non-blocking", sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Presumably, you allow script_1 to complete and return before attempting to start the poll? ie client-side, you start the poll for listener.php in the `success` (or `.done()`) handler of the jQuery code that called the 7za script.

Comment: I've added the jquery script in the question :)  I start both at the same time, but the ajax request to listener.php wait until the first script is complete... :(

Comment: Wow thank you Beetroot-Beetroot! I very appreciate that. (btw, I like your nickname)

Comment: Thanks, looks better, I will modify some part of my code accordingly to yours. But there's one problem (I think), backup.manager.php call the popen command. When it succeed, it's because the command is completed (100%). So no point of calling the listen() command in the success function to monitor the progress. Or maybe I don't properly understand your code correctly?

Comment: Jay, from a client-side perspective, initiating the `listen()` poll in the success function makes perfect sense. The way it was coded before, you had to rely on a 500ms timeout, which provided no guarantee that the server had even *started* running the `backup.manager.php` task let alone completed it. The way I coded it, completion of `backup.manager.php` is the signal to the client that polling may start. Think of it as a client-side application with remotely-supplied services and it should make more sense.

Comment: ... but I see what you mean about `popen` (and its while loop) having completed 100%. In order to monitor the progress of what is currently in the `while( !feof($fp) ){...}` loop, you need to allow `backup.manager.php` to exit as soon as it has *initiated* the job - as a background task or batch. Take another look at my [Run a batch file from my website](http://tinyurl.com/b79doul) answer and you will see that unix `nohup` command in my `run_in_background()` function would allow `backup.manager.php` to exit in that way.

Comment: Two alternative approaches exist; (a) [websocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), or (b) [long-polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_polling#Long_polling). Both are more complicated.

Comment: Okay I understand. I've changed my backup.manager.php code to return immediatly a result and run the 7za proccess in the background, but the listen.php page still wait for the 7za tool to complete before returning any results. (Post edited for full backup.manager.php script)

Comment: Jay, I've not seen a background task brought into life that way. Does the jQuery `success` function fire in response to `flush();`?

Comment: No :( but the flush() function is when I puit the script in the address bar and I want to know what it's doing (debug purpose)...

Comment: Jay, for the client-side code, it's critical (at least with my version of the javascript) that the success function fires at that point, otherwise the progress poll won't start. There may be a way to orchestrate the entire backup in `backup.manager.php`, however my experience led me to use two files (both PHP) (a) the "initiator" and (b) the "doer". My pattern (already referenced) allows the initiator to return (200) allowing the client's success function to kick off the monitor poll, with the doer still running as a batch job on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to call the command for each individual file.

It is going to be slower, but it is safer to manage with file cause errors and which files was properly inserted in the archive.

I'll try to find something faster is the direcotry to archive got 10 000 icons file for exemple. Maybe 5 files at a time instead of one file at a time.

This code was intended for testing purposes, the code is **not optimized at all** for production.

index.html jquery script:

```
var state = 0;
var jobid = '';
var timeout;
var jobfiles;
var jobpaths = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log('Sending');
        var path = $("input").val();
        x('state 1 getting info - infpb');
        state = 1;
        $.ajax({
            url:'backup.manager.php?json&path='+encodeURI(path)+'&type=0&state='+state, 
            dataType:'json', 
            success:function(data)
            {

                jobid = data['stats']['jobid'];
                jobfiles = data['stats']['totalfiles'];
                var jobsize = data['stats']['totalsize'];
                for(var i = 0, len = jobfiles; i < len; i++) {
                    jobpaths.push(data[i]['File']);
                }
                state = 2;
                x('state 2 - infpb stop (Information retrieved, launch backup) '+jobfiles+' files with '+jobsize+' bytes');
                backup_launch(jobid);

            }
        });
    });
});
function x(x) {
    $("#l").append(x+"<br>");   
}
var curfileid = 0;
function backup_launch(jobid) {
    x('jobid: '+jobid+' on state '+state);
    $.ajax({
        url:'backup.manager.php',
        data: {
            'json': 1,
            'jobid': jobid,
            'state': state,
            'path': jobpaths[curfileid]
        },
        dataType:'json', 
        success:function(data)
        {

            if(curfileid < jobfiles) {
                x((curfileid+1)+' / '+jobfiles);
                    curfileid++;
                    backup_launch(jobid);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            x(["backup.manager error", textStatus, errorThrown, jobid].join(": "));
        }
    });
}
function listen(jobid) {

    $.ajax({
        url:'backup.listener.php?json&jobid='+jobid, 
        dataType:'json', 
        success:function(data)
        {
            var curfile = data['curfile'];
            var totalfiles = data['totalfiles'];
            var p = curfile * 100 / totalfiles;
            x('File '+curfile+' out of '+totalfiles+' progress%: '+p);
            timeout = setTimeout("listen('"+jobid+"')", 500);

        }
    });
}
```

backup.manager.php

```
set_time_limit(0);
require('../functions.php');
session_start();



$keepCPUlow_lastlookup = time();
$keepCPUlow_mindelay = 60;
function keepCPUlow() {
    global $keepCPUlow_lastlookup, $keepCPUlow_mindelay;
    if((time() - $keepCPUlow_lastlookup) > $keepCPUlow_mindelay) {
        $keepCPUlow_lastlookup = time();
        getSysload(75, 1000);   // Max %, wait time in ms
    }
}



$state = isset($_GET['state']) ? $_GET['state'] : 0;
if($state == '1') {
    //
    $json = isset($_GET['json']) ? true : false;// Result should be in json format
    $path = isset($_GET['path']) ? $_GET['path'] : ''; // Path of the file or folder to backup
    $type = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : ''; // Type - not very useful, for now

    //0. Assign a jobid for this job, it will help retrieve realtime information about this task
    $jobid = hash('md4', (time().uniqid().session_id()));
    //Store the current status (0) job not started
    $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['status'] = 0; //Not started... yet

    // 1. Retrive list of files and stats
    $fileslist = array(); //Will contain the list of files
    $files_totalsize = 0; // Total size of files

    // Check if file or folder
    if(is_dir($path)) {
        //Path is a folder, get the list of files
        $files = getFilelist($path);


        foreach($files as $file) { //For each files
            if(!is_dir($file['File'])) { //That is not a directory
                $files_totalsize = $files_totalsize+$file['Filesize']; //Increment toal size
                $cpumon = keepCPUlow(); //if($cpumon[1]) echo ">CPU BURN".$cpumon[0]."<";

            }
        }

        $files_total = count($files); // Number of files
    } else {
        $files_totalsize = $files_totalsize+getFilesize($path);

        $files_total = 1;
    }


    $files['stats'] = array("totalfiles"=>$files_total, "jobid"=>$jobid, "totalsize"=>$files_totalsize);

    //Store infos in session
    $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['totalfiles'] = $files_total;
    $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['totalsize'] = $files_totalsize;
    $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['path'] = is_dir($path) ? $path.'\\*' : $path;
    $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['currentfile'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['currentfile_path'] = '';
    $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['bname'] = "SafeGuard_".$jobid.".".$GLOBALS["backup_ext"];
    $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['blocation'] = "D:\\";


    // 2. return to app and wait for ready confirmation
    if(isset($_GET['json'])) {
        echo json_encode($files);
    }
    exit();
}
else if($state == '2') {

    $jobid = isset($_GET['jobid']) ? $_GET['jobid'] : 0;
    $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['currentfile'] = 0;

    // 3. When app appove backup, 
    //      - Write infos to DB
    //      - Zip all files into 1 backup file
    $datebackup = time();
    $bckpstatus = 1; //In progress

    //$pathtobackup = $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['path'];
    $pathtobackup = isset($_GET['path']) ? $_GET['path'] : "--";

    $backupname = $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['bname'];
    $backuplocation = $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['blocation'];
    /*
    $query = "INSERT INTO backups (watchID, path, datebackup, checksum, sizeori, sizebackup, bckpcomplete)
            VALUES ($watchID, '{$path}', '{$datebackup}', '', '{$files_totalsize}', '', '{$bckpstatus}')"; 


    $sth = $db->prepare($query);

    $db->beginTransaction();
    $sth->execute();
    $db->commit();
    $sth->closeCursor();
    */



    if( ($fp = popen("7za a -t7z ".$GLOBALS["backup_compression"]." \"".$backuplocation.$backupname."\" \"".$pathtobackup."\"", "r")) ) {
        while( !feof($fp) ){

            fread($fp, 256);
            $num_lines = 1;
            $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['currentfile'] = $_SESSION['job'][$jobid]['currentfile']+$num_lines;
            $num_lines = 0;

            flush();
            echo '1';
        }
        pclose($fp);
    }




}
```